# how to make grub always select the default option, even if first boot fails?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, grub

we have a temporary requirement to have several small PCs running ubuntu 9.10 running 24/7 in an environment where the mains power isn't very reliable. The machines are in a remote location and hard to get to.

The problem I'm getting is when the power goes, it often fails twice in the space of about 30 seconds.

Grub is set so that if there is a failure during boot, it stops at the grub boot option screen the next time the power comes up. Someone needs to attach a keyboard and press the enter key for it to boot. I've been going through the grub manual and I can't find how to change this.

How can I set grub to always select the default option, no matter what happened on the last boot?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Could you add you current grub.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=64857

Answer (score 1):

under debian with grub-legacy you can use grub-reboot for this

```
# grub-reboot 2
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.


GNU GRUB  version 0.97  (640K lower / 3072K upper memory)

   [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For
     the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command
     completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
     completions of a device/filename. ]
grub> savedefault --once --default=2
grub> quit

Do you want to reboot now? [y/N]
```